# multiple maven repositories for gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

If I have multiple maven repositories specified in a gradle build, I am expecting that if gradle cannot find a dependency in one of the repositories it should just try the other ones. Instead, it fails on the first repository (internal company nexus repo) for a dependency that does not exists there and fails the build

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = 'http://mavencentral.it.att.com:8084/nexus/content/groups/att-public-group'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/' }
}
```

---

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':metadata-security:compile'.
>   > Artifact
>   'spring-security-kerberos-core.jar
>   (org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-kerberos-core:1.0.0.M2)'
>   not found. Searched in the following locations:
>   http://mavencentral.it.att.com:8084/nexus/content/groups/att-public-group/
>   org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-kerberos-core/1.0.0.M2/spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2.jar

Comment: Try running the build with `--debug`. It likely means that Gradle found a descriptor (pom.xml) but not the artifact itself.

Comment: And considering that URL, I can confirm that. :) I have no idea why the jar would be missing.

Comment: that was it .. pom is there and not the jar. Thanks

Comment: Adeel, you appear to be within AT&T. Could you get in touch with me? Just look me up.

Comment: @MarkVieira: do you want to post your comment as an answer, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Mark Viera in the comments:

> Try running the build with --debug. It likely means that Gradle found
>   a descriptor (pom.xml) but not the artifact itself.

That is, it was missing the jar file (as confirmed by the OP).